# MySQL: Limiting LEFT OUTER JOIN / Left outer join where id = #

Tags: php, mysql, sql

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibWdZsNrsUp5QvtYFJHDJt/0

I'm trying to load all entries from custom_fields, left join with custom_field_filter on ID = fieldid. However I need the JOIN to only happen in fields where custom_field_filter.formid = 6.

You can see the entry with name Status is loaded 3 times, which i don't want. I **only want to load the selected row with a formid of 6**, and also **all the other custom_fields rows**.

**Basically select and show the entire custom_fields table + LEFT JOIN with custom_Field_filter only where custom_Field_filter.formid=6.**

Of course if i do a WHERE clause, it wouldn't load all entries from custom_fields. So how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the related  clause with AND operator in ON clause

```
    SELECT `custom_fields`.*, `custom_field_filter`.`fieldid` as `selected` 
    FROM `custom_fields` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `custom_field_filter` 
    ON `custom_fields`.`ID` = `custom_field_filter`.`fieldid` 

        AND `custom_field_filter`.`formid` = 6

    ORDER BY `custom_fields`.`ID` ASC
```

the where clause on  the left joined table work as an inner join  ..  instead the use of a condition on the ON clause  preserve the left join

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks! 
Reference https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRAVx44U2NpM7yoeNPqJCP/1